# Is there any alternative way to change the Scaffold drawer width?

Tags: mobile, material-design, flutter

Currently Flutter Material directly not supporting editing Scaffold drawer controller. There is issue opened in their library to set width of drawer.
Is there any we can access and change width? or Is there custom scaffold implementation exist to change the behaviour?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<strike>Just copy the [Drawer source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/09276bea258737e11b109e227f70eac94a4e1691/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/drawer.dart) to a `MyDrawer` class and change `_kWidth` there.</strike>

As @RémiRousselet suggested wrapping the `Drawer` with

```
SizedBox( width: myWith: child: myDrawer )
```

Is a much better way.

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping `Drawer` into a `SizedBox(width: myWith)` do the same thing ?

Comment: Thanks GünterZöchbauer and remi . SizedBox works better.

Comment: Is the width going to be in pixels?

Comment: Yes, in pixels.

Comment: The return type `SizedBox` isn't a `Drawer` when I attempt to wrap

Comment: @DanMossa why do you think that is a problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that means you don`t have to return a Drawer widget to Scaffod`s drawer property ?

Comment: @FFur https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/Scaffold.html "drawer" expects just a Widget